# Filtering heaptrack data for size

Tags: c++, unix, gperftools, heap-profiling

I recorded a *.gz file with heaptrack for my application. I want to use it to find out how much memory is wasted by using small allocations.

Now my question is: Is it possible to filter the gz or data files created by heaptrack so only allocations with a certain maximum size remain?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Open your *.gz file with heaptrack_gui.

$heaptrack_gui *.gz

And check Summary or go to Bottom-Up tap then you can see memory Peak, allocated and leaked with location.